# Programming questions

Tags: discussion, scope, programming

What should we do about programming questions like [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72/random-sudoku-generator-in-objective-c)?

Are they on-topic or should they be closed (or migrated to SO)?

Answer (score 8):

I think most questions that ask for implementations *in a specific language* are offtopic here. Possible exceptions are questions like "How do I deal with language peculiarity X when implementing nifty thing Y?" if you can not expect the average programmer to have encountered and understood Y.

In this particular case, the OP did not even ask for help implementing something but asked for a complete software package. I feel that this is *definitely* out of our mandate as the underlying problem/task is not related to computer science.

A question asking for how to solve problem X algorithmically is always ontopic, imho.

Comment: "algorithmically" being, IMO, the important part. We should deal with theory, not practice (implementation).

Comment: Agreed. Beware the grey zone, though. "How to adapt algorithm X so it performs well on realistic CPU/memory  architectures?" is relevant and ontopic, imho, as long as no *specific* language, OS or architecture is targeted.

Answer (score 5):

This particular question seems to be very programming-oriented, but I imagine that with small tweaks it could be more general-CS friendly ? Designing sudoku puzzles is an interesting problem because of the unique-solution requirement.

Comment: Agreed, if it modified to become a question about algorithms that can be on-topic, but right now in its current form it is a programming question, and assuming that it stays in this form what should we do?

Comment: well since we *are* in private beta, may be some coaching for the OP is in order ?

Comment: @Suresh Yes, and I think the OP of the question has been given a fair bit of coaching now.

Comment: If we are discussing X strategy vs. Y strategy, then it makes it more CS specific, else asking for a solution, that also in a specific language, lets language specifics creep in.

Answer (score 3):

Just a reminder: **We will not migrate *anything* off of this site during the private beta**, or even early public beta. Please do not flag such questions asking for migrations, **they will be declined!**

This is the point in your site's lifecycle where you must, as a community, determine which questions will be allowed. It is therefore important that you discuss and vote, both on obviously-off-topic questions and edge-cases, as these will help you establish a clear and consistent message for future instances of the same.